# How to display numbers in pairs using for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to use for loop for my R shiny app which is more complex than just displaying the numbers and characters. Hence, I have written a much simpler version here. Does anyone know how to display the following output using for loop?

```
"1,a"
"2,b"
"3,c"
```

So I have tried using the codes below:

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  for(j in c("a","b","c")) {
    
    print(paste(i,j,sep = ","))
  }}
```

However, it produces this output:

```
[1] "1,a"
[1] "1,b"
[1] "1,c"
[1] "2,a"
[1] "2,b"
[1] "2,c"
[1] "3,a"
[1] "3,b"
[1] "3,c"
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: `cbind(paste0(rep(1:3, each=3), ",", letters[1:3]))`

Comment: @Roman I've recently been scolded for violating SO etiquette by posting solutions in comments. I'm not scolding you but please note that just a moment ago I've posted a solution, which had taken me some minutes to put together, only to find that you had pointed to roughly the same solution in a comment. I'm wondering why you don't post your solutions as full answers. This would help avoid these interferences.

Comment: You are getting the numbers repeated because you are iterating over both 1:3 and a,b,c you only need a single for loop if you want to do this with a loop, which I would advise against (as below).

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann this question or answer is so fundamental easy basic R that I'm not sure if the asker really search for such solution, rather searching for other crazy things. Thus, I'm only proofing with my comment if my answer is really true.  And now Richard J. Acton c&p and answered it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably only need one index `i`.

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  print(paste(i, c("a","b","c")[i], sep = ","))
}
# [1] "1,a"
# [1] "2,b"
# [1] "3,c"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @debster You're welcome, also try `letters[i]` instead of `c("a","b","c")[i]`!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason to be using one this is not a task best accomplished with a for loop. You can take advantage of the fact that `paste` is vectorised and do this:

`paste(1:3, letters[1:3], sep = ",")`

The `sep` argument to the paste function permits you to stitch together 2 vectors with a given string.

Comment: Hi @Richard, yes I know by doing this would be much more easier. I have edited my question above. I am trying to use for loops in my R shiny app reactive function, so I have re-written the codes in a much simpler way here.

Comment: There may be a vectorised or functional style map operation that would permit you to do this in your shiny app without using a for loop also, could you post a slightly fuller picture of what you are trying to do I think you have abstracted away a little too much.

Comment: Thanks @Richard. I have found the solution :D